# Nesting conditionals in Java

Tags: java

**The Problem**

Given the following code:

```
if (enforceLength && rawContents.length != recordLength) {
```

Right now if `enforceLength` and `rawContents` does not match `recordLength`, it returns true and triggers our warning system. Some of our `recordLength` however are `HEADER_DIFF` characters longer than the `rawContents.length`.

So we are hoping to put an `or` on `rawContents.length` so that it can either match `recordLength` or `recordLength + HEADER_DIFF`.

**Question**

Is there a straightforward way to create an OR conditional on just the second part of this if statement? i.e. so that it triggers the alert if `rawContents.length` does not equal `recordLength` but it does not if `recordLength` happens to be exactly `HEADER_DIFF` longer than expected.

**A failed attempt**

One attempt that failed:

```
if (enforceLength && rawContents.length != recordLength + HEADER_DIFF 
  || rawContents.length != recordLength)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem with trying to fold too much into one `if` statement through an irrational fear of the arrow pattern.

Surely this would be much clearer.

```
    if (enforceLength) {
        // Can be correct or out by HEADER_DIFF
        if(!(rawContents.length == recordLength + HEADER_DIFF || rawContents.length == recordLength)) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: @tobias_k Actually - IMHO - it would be better. You can now put your `else` on either `if` and be accurate on what alternative you are tracking. An `else` on the original code would hit if `enforceLength` was `false` **OR** the length was bad.

Answer (score 2):

The not-or-ious logic knot

```
if (enforceLength && rawContents.length != recordLength
        && rawContents.length != recordLength + HEADER_DIFF) {
```

Maybe negatives are more understandable

```
if (enforceLength && !(rawContents.length == recordLength
        || rawContents.length == recordLength + HEADER_DIFF)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Fail if neither of the 2 conditions is true:

```
if (enforceLength && !(rawContents.length == recordLength + HEADER_DIFF || rawContents.length == recordLength))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you just need to use parentheses around the OR, and replace it with an AND, as such:

```
if (enforceLength && (rawContents.length != recordLength && rawContents.length != recordLength + HEADER_DIFF))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a nested if?

```
if (enforceLength)
{
    if(test for header diff)
     {
        rawContents.length != recordLength + HEADER_DIFF 
     }

    else
    {
     rawContents.length != recordLength)
    }
}
```

It is more convoluted but eaiser to understand.

Comment: This is not a nested if. That's not even valid syntax.

Comment: Missed the last }, thanks for pointing it out. The contents of the nested if are pesudo code as there wasn't enough information in the post to determine how they were checking if they had to test for the header diff and I didn't have the ability to post comments at the time.